# AWS Lambda Python - How to construct Dockerfile with mulitple source packages

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda

I need to construct a Docker container for my python project so I can deploy it to AWS ECR and trigger the container job based on the day of the week. I am struggling with properly copying the source files into the docker container since I have several source packages.

Here is the project structure:

```
Dockerfile
requirements.txt
src/
    Package1/
         src1.py
    Package2/
        src2.py
    Package3/
        src3.py
    Runner/
        mainRunner.py
```

Where mainRunner.py contains my handler method.

mainRunner.py contents example:

```
from Package1 import src1
def handler(event, context):
    src1.main()
```

Here are the Dockerfile contents:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
RUN mkdir /src
ADD src /src/
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 cache purge && pip3 install -U pip wheel setuptools && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR src/Runner/
ENV PYTHONPATH /src
CMD ["mainRunner.handler"]
```

When I run the docker container locally, I receive the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): Unable to import module 'mainRunner': No module named 'mainRunner'`

I tried to exec in the container locally and I cannot find the source code files. I was able to use this same Dockerfile with a python base image perfectly fine (FROM python:3.9) - except the CMD was different for the python base image - `CMD python3 mainRunner.py`. What am I doing wrong here?